# Copying files from Remote machine using sftp in python

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I want to be able to copy a file from a remote machine using either scp, ssh or sftp in python. The best way I've found is to use ssh with sftp. I've been trying to use this example to accomplish what I need to do.

```
import paramiko
import os

paramiko.util.log_to_file('logfile.log')

host = "101.102.103.104"
port = 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
password = "pass"
username = "user"

sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

filepath = '~/remote/file'
localpath = '~/local/file'
sftp.get(filepath, localpath)

sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

When I do this, I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 19, in <module>
    sftp.get(filepath, localpath)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Is there something I'm missing or not doing correctly?

Thank you

Comment: this call sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport) is returning None. Figure out why thats happening

Comment: well obviously your `sftp` object was not created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your username and password are initialized but never used. You need to call *connect* for your *transport* object

```
password = "pass"
username = "user"
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I completely missed that. Thanks for pointing it out. But now when I run it, I get an IOError saying the file doesn't exist in sftp.get(filepath, localpath) but they definitely do exist

Comment: make sure all directories in the localpath exist before calling sftp.get()

Comment: I figured it out, it's because I have to provide the full path as oppose to using "~/"

Answer (score 0):

The [API](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Transport-class.html#__init__) specifies you have to provide a "socket like object" to `paramiko.Transport()` you provide a tuple. I guess that's the problem.

**UPDATE:**
Although specified otherwise in the docs the tuple is ok.

Comment: The documentation says that, but the [source code](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.transport-pysrc.html) (particularly, line 281 and just after) shows that `Transport` does accept a tuple.

Comment: Yes, i have just found out, too. Well as i said only a "guess" don't have paramiko available for testing right now.